How should I apply the 2.5σ rule of cut-off distance in the case of reduced units?
According to the book of Frenken & Smit, Page 35-37, the cut-off distance in the case of LJ (Lennard-Jones) particles:

Equal to $2.5 \sigma$; where $\sigma$ is the equilibrium distance in the LJ formula

In the case of reduced units, $\sigma=1.0$. So, the cut-off distance becomes $2.5$ no matter what type of particle I am simulating or no matter what the periodic distance is.
Isn't that a problem?

If you read on to the end of Frenkel and Smit's chapter, the very first exercise is an exercise in reduced units:

Typical sets of Lennard-Jones parameters for argon and krypton are (Allen and Tildesley, 1987):

$\sigma_{\mathrm{Ar}}$ = 3.41 Å, $\epsilon_{\mathrm{Ar}}/\mathrm{k_B}$ = 119.8 K and
$\sigma_{\mathrm{Kr}}$ = 3.38 Å, $\epsilon_{\mathrm{Kr}}/\mathrm{k_B}$ = 164.0 K


Work through the rest of the exercise if you'd like, but let's ask: how would you then simulate a mixture of argon and krypton?
Frankly, the simplest thing to do is to just use sensible real units. (In the MD software LAMMPS that is how this option is uncreatively named.) Just declare that your simulation software will handle distances in angstroms (in which case we can just use the sigma's as-is), and energies in, say, kcal/mol (so, since $\mathrm{k_B}$ = 1.987 cal/mol.K, we will have:

$\epsilon_{\mathrm{Ar}}$ = 0.238 kcal/mol and
$\epsilon_{\mathrm{Kr}}$ = 0.326 kcal/mol.

Done! Solved! "But what cutoffs should we use?" you may ask. Well, if we go all the way back to the founding paper (A. Rahman (1964), Phys. Rev. 136, A405), the answer is obvious:

This interaction was assumed to extend up to a range $R=2.25\sigma$, so that a particle interacts with all particles situated within a sphere of that radius;
$V(2^{1/6}\sigma) = -\epsilon$ is the minimum of $V(r)$ and at $r=R$,
$V \sim -0.03 \epsilon$.


So, 2.25 $\sigma$. Or 2.5 $\sigma$? Which $\sigma$?
As always, the precise answer actually depends on your context:

If you're trying to replicate experimental results -- you're gonna be much further off than 3% anyway, so just choose some nice round number like 9 Å or 10 Å and call it a day.
If you're doing precision statistical mechanical theory, you have to vary your cutoff and see what happens (or use long-range dispersion corrections), so you will find out along the way if your cutoff even matters (and if it does, are you really doing molecular dynamics, or are you doing cutoff science?).
If you're using a force field someone else devised, you don't get a say. Use their cutoff. Or you're inventing your own whole new force field, and you will have to defend that to the referees. (... just kidding, they probably wouldn't even notice!)


But let's say we're scientific heroes, and we will use those reduced units.
Well, then your options are to set:

$\sigma^*_{\mathrm{Ar}} = 1, \epsilon^*_{\mathrm{Ar}} = 1; \sigma^*_{\mathrm{Kr}} = 0.9912, \epsilon^*_{\mathrm{Kr}} = 1.369$, or:
$\sigma^*_{\mathrm{Ar}} = 1.009, \epsilon^*_{\mathrm{Ar}} = 0.7305; \sigma^*_{\mathrm{Kr}} = 1, \epsilon^*_{\mathrm{Kr}} = 1$
(To experience additional pain, you may certainly set $\sigma^*$ of one element to 1 and $\epsilon^*$ of the other element to 1.)

Notice how reduced quantities work:

The asterisks denote reduced quantities, like little shurikens embedded in your formulae as sacred relics of the hard path to molecular dynamics mastery.
They are unitless quantities. (Distances are all lengths divided by a length scale; energies are all energies divided by an energy scale; and so on.)
By formally, painfully honouring their unitless nature, you avoid absurd koans like "what does $\sigma = 1.2 \sigma$ mean?". But I have found the following notation useful:

the undecorated $\sigma$ will always denote the length scale;
subscripted $\sigma^*_{\mathrm{something}}$ will always denote a unitless parameter of a force field
if we hang on to our subscripts, the formulation $\sigma_{\mathrm{Ar}} = 1 \sigma; \sigma_{\mathrm{Kr}} = 0.9912 \sigma$ still makes sense, denoting unit-full distances as multiples of $\sigma$;
a generic $r^*$ will always denote a unitless distance, and a generic $r$ could denote a unit-full distance (for example, "the average distance between argon atoms was $r^* = 0.84$, but the average distance between krypton atoms was $r = 0.91 \sigma$.")



What should the cutoff be? Again, the precise answer depends on your context; they are in fact the exact same answers as above.

My context is: I am writing an MC simulation program using LJ pair potential. I am trying to be sure if my program works properly or not.

Then you need to use whatever "settings" your benchmark uses. For example, the Kob-Andersen model has composition 80% A particles and 20% B particles with: s*AA = 1 s*BB = 0.8 s*AB = 0.88 cutoff* = 2.5; e*AA = 1 e*BB = 0.5 e*AB = 1.5
parameters from Phys Rev Lett 120, 165501 (2018). Pretty unambiguous.

At the moment I am using only one particle: argon.

Well, then the argon LJ potential should have a unitless sigma of 1 and unitless R of 2.5 (or 2.25 if you're trying to replicate A. Rahman's calculations!). Or 3 if that's the publication you're trying to replicate. Or 1.1226 if you want the WCA quasi-hard-sphere ... point is, look at the publication you're trying to replicate and follow that.
